# View traffic volume in home network (dd-wrt)

Tags: wireless-router, home-networking, dd-wrt

I have a homenetwork with a dd-wrt router.  How can I get a good  overview of the traffic towards Internet (Better than the dd-wrt screens) over different periods, by device and in total.  Need to be able to group destinations that are essentially the same (Like Netflix or Microsoft upgrades).

I have a Windows netbook attached by LAN to the router.  I will perhaps change the router anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking too much for a consumer grade router, remember they only have 400-800Mhz RISK chips usually, theres a limit to how detailed they can be without slowing core function. Look at running a PFSense box to get more control like that.

Comment: What would be to much? Storingdata? Processing and presenting it? Routing Internet traffic through another box? Internal free RAM is 100M. Sounds a little bit low for keeping track of 100+ G/month on the router only.

Comment: Investigating Netflow:http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Network_traffic_analysis_with_netflow_and_ntop